# Restrict Payload for some method CommonsRequestLoggingFilter Spring

Tags: java, spring, filter, log4j, payload

I am using `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to log payload of incoming request . But for one method i don't want to log the payload as it contains user confidential data . I have following configuration in `web.xml`

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>includePayload</param-name>
            <param-value >true</param-value>
         </init-param>  
        <init-param>
            <param-name>includeQueryString</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>MaxPayloadLength</param-name>
            <param-value>10000</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Help me in restricting with one method .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own class extending CommonsRequestLoggingFilter and in that class you could do:-

```
@Override     
protected String createMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String prefix, String suffix) {
      //based on uri you could print payload or not.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```java
    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
            @Override
            protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
                if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/myapp/service1/")) {
                    return false;
                }
                return logger.isDebugEnabled();
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
```

Although I am not very happy with this solution and still trying to find something more elegant.